# PowerShell process on first match only

Tags: powershell

```
Is there a way in powershell to match file against files in a directory and on the     
first match write the file in the directory to another directory
file            directory      output directory 
test1.txt       test3.txt          test1.txt since this matched and it was the first   
                                               match. only write this one process ends.
test2.txt       test2.txt                     
test3.txt       test1.txt
```

This is as far as I got I hear there is a -First parameter would that be needed here?

```
$objFolder = "C:\Users\Bruce\Serena\"  (directory)
$objFile = "C:\Users\Bruce\process.txt"  (File)
$outFile = "C:\Users\Bruce\Deploy\"  Output Directory
$FolderReferenceContents = Get-ChildItem $objFolder 
$FolderDifferenceContents = Get-Content $objFile 
 $Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $FolderReferenceContents -DifferenceObject
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to pipe to the `Select-Object` cmdlet.

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $FolderReferenceContents -DifferenceObject $FolderDifferenceContents | Select -First 1
```

Ok, I just tested this, and it works. If you get errors you need to check your paths.

```
$objFolder = "C:\Users\Bruce\Serena\"  #(directory)
$objFile = "C:\Users\Bruce\process.txt"  #(File)
$outFile = "C:\Users\Bruce\Deploy\"  #Output Directory
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (gc $objFile) -DifferenceObject (gci $objFolder|select -ExpandProperty Name) -ExcludeDifferent -IncludeEqual|select -first 1 -Expand InputObject | %{Copy-Item "objFolder\$_" -Dest $outFile}
```

Comment: Can I just add out-file $outfile to get the output written

Comment: you can pipe to that, yes. At the end of the line add `| Out-File $outfile` and you may want `-Append` as well depending on your situation.

Comment: getting cannot bind argument to parameter 'ReferenceObject' because it is null?????

Comment: So make sure that $FolderReferenceContents is populated with data first?

Comment: my process.txt contains